# Android - Changing 3D model on Vuforia

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, vuforia

How can I change the 3D Modelo on Vuforia? Now I'm viewing the Teapot of the samples, but I want to change it.

I've read this posts on the official forum:

[How to render Static 3D Model](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/How-To-Render-Static-3D-Models-Using-OpenGL-ES)

[Replace 3D model](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/replace-3d-model-different-3d-model?page=1)

[Customizing 3D model](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/customizing-3d-model-java-class)

But I haven't gotten success.

If I make a custom object with the arrays with obj2opengl and I create a new class for this new object, Android Studio shows me an error like "Too much code" in a file, and I can't compile the app.

I think that reading the arrays of .obj 3D from a file may cause a runtime overload.

Any idea to render any other 3D model? I'm going crazy

Answer (score 0):

hi u should download or buy 3D MODEL from net and attach them to unity asset in project then drag them to scene and use

Comment: I need to load it in Android, not in Unity =(